# Twilio.MVC ValidateRequest on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor, twilio

I am trying to get the twilio.MVC helper attribute ValidateRequest to work on a MVC 4 controller running in AppHarbor.  I can't seem to get it to work and I assume it is because my app is running behind a load balancer.  I've tried supplying the UrlOverride parameter in the call, but I can't seem to get it correct.  Assuming my appharbor app url = myapp.apphb.com, my controller = callhandler, my action = handlecall, how should I be calling the ValidateRequest attribute?

```
ValidateRequest[("MYAUTHTOKEN","myapp.apphb.com")]
```

Doesn't seem to work, I constantly get a 403 Forbidden error back.

Just an FYI- I am decorating the individual MVC action and not the entire controller at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody runs into this same issue, I got this working by specifying the UrlOverride as a Named Parameter along with the controller and the action, like so:

```
ValidateRequest[("MYAUTHTOKEN", UrlOverride="http://myapp.apphb.com/controller/action")]
```